# "set hidden" leaves many *empty* buffers. Can I automatically get rid of them?

Tags: buffers, split, hidden-buffers

I recently added `set hidden` to my `vimrc` script because I didn't always want to `:w`rite a file before `:e`diting another file. (With `set nohidden`, which is the default, this resulted in a `E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)` error).

Setting `hidden` solved this problem, but introduced a new one. Sometimes, I split the window (`ctrl-w n`) before I `:e`dit a file. This creates an empty buffer for each split that I have done. This is of course not what I want.

So, is there some setting or autocommand or anything that I am not aware of that gets rid of unused empty buffers automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cut out the middle man. If you want to edit a file in a split, use `:split file.txt`.

It is the very nature of using `<C-W>n` that creates these new buffers. It's like using the `:new` command, which is wasteful if you plan to immediately edit some other file.

If you like the visual confirmation of seeing the new window before editing the file, you could use `<C-W>s` which opens a split with the current buffer (so you'll see two of the same file) and then proceed to use `:edit file.txt`.